# malloc() returns NULL on certain sizes

Tags: c, bitmap, embedded, malloc

I'm currently developing a C application for a homebrewed' Nintendo Switch (therefore an embedded system on an ARM CPU), and I came across something weird - which I can't wrap my mind around.

I'm using a UI library to render an user interface to the screen, and I'm dynamically generating bitmaps to show (QR codes). The whole bitmap generation works fine, tested that - everything's good, but here comes the problem:

To render a bitmap to screen, it uses stb_image, and at some bitmap dimensions, it simply fails to render. After hours of tracking down the source code of the UI library and stb_image, I found that it fails to allocate memory for the bitmap in some cases (`malloc()` returns `NULL`).

The memory allocation in stb_image is as follows:

```c
out = (stbi_uc*) stbi__malloc(target * s->img_x * s->img_y);
```

`target` is always 4 for bitmaps so it boils down to `4 * resX * resY` bytes to allocate. Also, `stbi_malloc` simply wraps to a `malloc()` call.

These are the test cases I had:

| Dimension | Bytes to alloc | Worked? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 170x170 | 115600 | Nope |
| 257x257 | 264196 | Yes |
| 259x259 | 268324 | Nope |
| 260x260 | 270400 | Yes |
| 261x261 | 272484 | Yes |
| 262x262 | 274576 | Yes |
| 263x263 | 276676 | Yes |
| 267x267 | 285156 | Nope |

As you can see, it only happens to a few dimensions, but it doesn't work **every time** for them, so it's not a random case, but something seems off with the non-working dimensions.

At this point, I'm completely unsure what this might be and any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The obvious question: how big is your heap and how much memory have you planned to use for the worst case?

Comment: a bit of a stupid question, are you sure it's not passing negative values to malloc, as malloc expects unsigned data, an other reason could be heap corruption, you could have overran a buffer that you previously allocated and you're looking at undefined behaviour, and the obvious one is that you're out of memory but it'd be kinda bizarre here.

Comment: The numbers in your table are printed directly from the code, or just your own expected interpretation? My first obvious step would be to print the actual size it tries to alloc.

Comment: @Devolus They _were_ my interpretation, but just checked logged out what stbi_malloc is trying to allocate, and it's exactly what I calculated in the table

Comment: @Cufox Yea, I logged it out, seems all fine, no negative values. Going to try to figure out the heap size of the Switch

Comment: @Lundin I wonder though, how can it be the heap size, if e.g. bigger allocations work (allocating 115600 doesn't work while allocation 264196 bytes works)

Comment: How did you determine these numbers? Do you try to allocate all of them and then get a list of what failed? Do you free memory somewhere else, after the first failed and before you try to alloc the next image?

Comment: @JohnnyVerbeek  What's the ***exact*** prototype for both `stbi__malloc()` and `malloc()` on that system?  Include the type of the argument passed to both and the definition of that type if it's not a basic type such as `unsigned short int`.  And **how big is that type**?  You're probably actually attempting to allocate an amount of memory modulo the max of that unsigned type, which is smaller than the values you ***think*** you're passing to the function.

Comment: @Devolus Exactly, I tried the resolutions above one by one and checked via `printf("%p", mem)` whether it prints 0x0 or a valid memory address. And yea, pretty sure stb_image also frees the memory again

Comment: @AndrewHenle We got `static void *stbi__malloc(size_t size)` and `extern void *malloc (size_t);`. `size_t` is a `long unsigned int`, where I tested on the switch: `sizeof(size_t) = 8`.

Comment: Here's what I evaluated on the switch using the native services: Total Memory Size: 3343908864, Used Memory Size: 3339976704, HeapRegionAddr: 0xD1E600000, HeapRegionSize: 6442450944

Comment: @AndrewHenle, `stbi__malloc` is just a wrapper for `malloc` unless the macro `STBI_MALLOC` has been redefined manually.

Comment: Are you calling `stbi__malloc` yourself, or do you call some of the loader functions which are calling it? Did you check that it is really the malloc call that fails, or did the loader return `null` and the issue may be some problem with the graphics file?

Comment: @Devolus Not calling it myself, the chain is actually `stbi_load_from_memory -> stbi_load_flip -> stbi_load_main -> stbi_bmp_load -> stbi_malloc`. I got printfs everywhere there to check at what exact point if fails, but the first fail is in stbi_malloc, hence all other calls return failures aswell. There's also a error string set, which is "outofmem", but that's just guessed by them because malloc failed and that's probably the most likely case.

Comment: Did you put a printf in `stbi__malloc`? Because that is not called directly, rather by `stbi__mad3sizes_valid` which can return `NULL` on its own if some of the conditions fail without even calling `stbi__malloc`.

Comment: @Devolus Ha you know what, the version of stb_image.h included in the UI rendering library doesn't seem to call these functions at all. So either it's outdated, or they removed it on purpose. [Here's](https://github.com/Adubbz/nanovg-deko3d/blob/master/include/nanovg/stb_image.h) the working tree of the stb_image.h I got!

Comment: @JohnnyVerbeek The correct way to trouble-shoot this is: if some situations don't work, then assume that the others merely _seem_ to work. These errors you describe are _symptoms_ and not likely the cause. You either have an undefined behavior bug somewhere or you are running out of heap or stack. If you don't know how big the heap is or have a plan for how much of it you are using, then that's the most likely problem.

Comment: Anyway, what's an "ARM"? Cortex M0 or Aarch64 or somewhere in between? Which one? Since you tagged this embedded, why are you even using heap allocation? Is this an actual embedded system or some manner of "PC in disguise"?

Comment: @Lundin It's a NVIDIA Tegra X1 SoC, which got 4 cores of an ARM Cortex-A57 in there. I'm not very skilled in this area, so not quite sure whether it's an embedded system or some PC in disguise, probably the latter. As I described above, I queried these values off the platform: Total Memory Size: 3343908864, Used Memory Size: 3339976704, HeapRegionAddr: 0xD1E600000, HeapRegionSize: 6442450944. I'm not sure though why the heap is almost twice as big as the actual physical RAM available

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much a PC :) As for your numbers, they seem to mix decimal and hex. And the debug could be anywhere, we can't really reproduce this or answer without more context. At a minimum post the full malloc code with all variable declarations.

Comment: @Lundin You mean the actual implementation of malloc()? Thats inside a static library, not sure if I can find the source code for that...

Comment: No, your application code using malloc. Since the problem is very unlikely related to some magic number combination passed to malloc and very likely related to bugs elsewhere in your program.